# Format spring Errors message arguments

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot web application and I reject a value in a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createSubmit(@ModelAttribute("createForm") CreateForm createForm, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    DateTime dt1 = createForm.getDt1();
    DateTime dt2 = createForm.getDt2();

    if (!dt1.isBefore(dt2)){
        result.rejectValue("fieldId", "validation.isbefore", new Object[]{dt1, dt2}, "first date must be before second");
    }
}
```

so, if date `dt1` is not before `dt2`, the value gets rejected. Now, I have pretty standard `ResourceBundleMessageSource` with this entry in `messages_en.properties`:

```
validation.isbefore = Start date {0} must be before end date {1}
```

When the validation error occurs though, I get a message `Start date 3/21/16 5:01 PM must be before end date 3/20/16 5:01 PM` (both `dt1` and `dt2` uses their `toString()` to format the message).

Now, `java.text.MessageFormat` does support some formatting, namely `{0,date,short}`. But that only works for `java.util.Date`, not Joda Time (or any other custom classes for that matter).

Is there a way to customize how are error message arguments formatted? I don't want to do it at the time of validation (in final code the validator itself is decoupled from the controller, have no info about selected language, so it does not know what date format to use).

Comment: Really, you shouldn't be dealing with presentation logic on the server.

Comment: @EngineerDollery well the server is responsible for generating HTML (it's spring MVC/Thymeleaf), so I have to deal with presentation / localization on the server.

Comment: HTML is for structure, css (and sometimes javascript) is responsible for presentation. Java is responsible for validation, business rules, and CRUD. You would need javascript to format this, but it should be easy if you have the date wrapped in an easy to identify div. Then the gui people can deal with the L&F issues leaving you to get on with writing server code. :)

Comment: well anyways, even that way you have to somehow pass the data from java to HTML (so that you can format it using CSS/JS). And how would you do that -- pass DateTime.toString and parse it in JS? That does not make sense..

Comment: You could arrange for all dates to be wrapped in a div in your html, something like this: <div class='datetime'>...</div>, then have a piece of javascript (maybe jquery, maybe not) that selects all datetime classes ($('.datetime')), which converts the contents to a date instance, and the replaces the content with a formatted version of the same. Pretty simple really, and allows your UI people to 'mess' with date formats without having to ask a java dev to go through the code and change them. Plus, it's a pretty common pattern, so it really does make some sense in a lot of places.

Comment: In your example, you could just change your message to be: validation.isbefore = Start date <div class='datetime'>{0}</div> must be before end date <div class='datetime'>{1}</div>

Comment: then you once more just tangle java with HTML. The localization file/module in my opinion really should not deal with divs/classes/etc. And even then you have toString of DateTime, eg. you have to somehow parse it back to javascript. It might work for DateTime, but will definitely work for custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the CustomDateEditor and WebBinding within your controller to format the dates.  You could try adding something like this to your controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
       @InitBinder
       public void customizeBinding (WebDataBinder binder) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "dt1",
                 new CustomDateEditor(dateFormatter, true));
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, "dt2",
                 new CustomDateEditor(dateFormatter, true));
       }

       @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String createSubmit(@ModelAttribute("createForm") CreateForm 
       createForm, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
            DateTime dt1 = createForm.getDt1();
            DateTime dt2 = createForm.getDt2();

            if (!dt1.isBefore(dt2)){
                 result.rejectValue("fieldId", "validation.isbefore", new 
                 Object[]{dt1, dt2}, "first date must be before second");
            }
        }

}
```

I used and modified this example from: http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-custom-property-editor/

Here's the official Spring documentation for the Built-In Property Editors: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion

Hopefully then it will be able to display the format that you want by using the format method when converting it to a String.

Otherwise, you may have to do something really weird and extend DateTime to your own date time and override the toString() method, but that seems like it may be too brute force of a solution.

```
 public class MyDateTime extends DateTime {

      @Override
      public toString() {
           return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd).format(this);
      }
 }
```

Then

```
MyDateTime dt1 = createForm.getDt1();
MyDateTime dt2 = createForm.getDt2();
```